# onMouseDown pointers inside a loop in rascal

Tags: rascal

In the following code I want each box (Figure) to have his own mousedown.
But after rendering all the boxes use the same file, the last read file.

```
    for(loc file <- lsFile){
       lsBox += box(
                    onMouseDown(bool (int butnr, map[KeyModifier,bool] modifiers) {
                        renderFile(file);
                        return true;
                    })
                );
    }
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(loc file <- lsFile){
   loc tmp = file;
   lsBox += box(
                onMouseDown(bool (int butnr, map[KeyModifier,bool] modifiers) {
                    renderFile(tmp);
                    return true;
                })
            );
}
```

The closure captures the file variable, not its value. So you slways have a reference to its last value. The tmp variable is newly allocated for each iteration, so it doesnot have this problem.